# Flutter Stripe CardField not working in web

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-web, flutter-stripe

I am trying to get a CardField from the [flutter_stripe](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe) package to appear on web. Simply with this code, a card field will display on ios and android. Though once I run on the app on Chrome, a blank line appears with the error, "Bad state: Source maps are not done loading".
I have the flutter_stripe and flutter_stripe_web package both installed and I cannot seem to figure this out. Any advice would be appreciated!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart';

void main() {
   runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
   const MyApp({super.key});

   @override
   MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
     CardFieldInputDetails? _card;
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return MaterialApp(
         title: 'Test',
         home: Scaffold(
           body: Column(
             children: [
               CardField(
                 cursorColor: Colors.black,
                 enablePostalCode: true,
                 countryCode: 'US',
                 postalCodeHintText: 'Enter the us postal code',
                 onCardChanged: (card) {
                   setState(() {
                     _card = card;
                   });
                 },
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
       );
     }
   }
```

[ios image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORk1i.png)
[web image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Onhc.png)

Comment: is your code working fine for flutter web ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to include Stripe.publishableKey = 'your publishable key' inside main()!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!  That's a surprising error to get given that fix!

Answer (score 2):

The flutter_stripe project only has [limited, experimental support for the web right now](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe#web-experimental).  [The maintainers recommend](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/discussions/785#discussioncomment-2945057) you use [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) instead.

If you really want to get the CardField working on the web I was going to suggest you post an issue to the flutter_stripe repo, but it [looks like you've already done so](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/issues/865).

Comment: Yes I did add it as an issue because in their example code the CardField works on ios, android, and web. Couldn't get it to work for my code.